# Allow SSL connection on port 8081 with nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have a problem to acces to the port 8081 in https.
Here you will find my configuration in nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    server_name _;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /upload {                                                     
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/upload;           
       proxy_set_header Host $host;                                   
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                       
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;   
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                    
       proxy_redirect http://localhost:8081upload https://localhost:8081/upload;                                            
    }     
}
```

The port is still avaible in http but not in https. It's telling me "fail secured connection".
Can you help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell `nginx` which private key to use. Using this

```
ssl_certificate_key ${file};
```

where `${file}` is your private key will make it work.

Quoting the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate_key):

> Specifies a file with the secret key in the PEM format for the given virtual server.

Comment: sorry I forgot to put this line in the post :
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;                                               But The problem is still there.

Comment: @Erylis01 I've got your question wrong, at it seems. So, the connection from `nginx` to the `backend` fails, right? If so, you've to provide details: What's running there, logs written by this application, relevant source code or config excerpts, etc.

Comment: I try to acces to the address https://domain:8081. I can acces to this adress in http but not in https. There is nothing in the acces.log and in the error.log there is "2016/07/21 11:38:39 [notice] 9565#9565: signal process started" whent I tried to connect to https://domain:8081.

Comment: @Erylis01 What's running on port 8081?

Comment: It's a script javascript

Comment: @Erylis01 And it offers `HTTPS`? If not: What are you trying to achieve with the directive `proxy_redirect http://localhost:8081upload https://localhost:8081/upload;`? If the script is running on the same machine as `nginx`, as it seems, I don't see much point in doing this. Just use `proxy_pass ...` and remove `proxy_redirect ...`. Besides this: There is a typo inside your `proxy_redirect ... ` directive: The first `upload` is missing a `/`.